# C# with SQL Server using Windows authentication

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-authentication

I'm facing a problem developing the app for the client that uses a SQL Server with Windows authentication only, so the situation is that there is a number of Windows accounts in Active Directory that can access the database and some application are using those accounts.

My problem is I have to develop a C# application that has to get any modification in specific table with a `SqlTableDependency` the only way to access the database is by using an administrator account; is there a way to define any of the defined accounts to connect using Windows authentication for users to execute the app developed?

And many thanks.

Comment: Windows authentication or not, the user accessing the DB must have enoghu privileges to do whatever the client program needs.

Comment: Just add your users AD accounts to an AD group which grants the minimum required permissions on SQL Server.

Comment: No i did some test and they have no privilege to access data base

Comment: Well yes, you will have to involve the IT department to grant them permissions.

Answer (score 3):

You make this assertion about [`SqlTableDependency`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SqlTableDependency/):

> The only way to access the database is by using Administrator account

But that is not correct. **ANY account can do this**, no matter what kind of authentication it uses, if the required security permissions are granted. You will need to find out the exact permissions this item uses and communicate with your client about granting those permissions to their users.

At this point there's a good chance your client will get uncomfortable... they may not have realized what they were asking for! But that's okay. Now you can have a real conversation about what their needs are. Perhaps they need a special (sql-auth-based) service account for this. Or perhaps they want to change the architecture so this runs as a background task on the server. It doesn't matter: the important part is you and the client are now making better-informed decisions about the application.

Comment: Thanks for the response but this application for auditing customer and other stuff it have to a desktop app in the audit departement not in the server

Comment: That's still fine. Again... this is a reason to talk with the client. If the app has a special purpose, it may need special security treatment, which may include a dedicated sql auth account, or a special Active Directory user with the required permissions granted. But the `Administrator`/`sa` account is **NEVER** the solution.